# What is my best option for Creating and refreshing my Placeholder?

Tags: c#, asp.net, timer, placeholder, timing

I need to use the CreateTable method to create my table, I then need my table to refresh all of the values every few seconds, I have tried using System.Threading.Thread.Sleep and using the Timers. However I am unable to get this to work due to various things for example table not being display or just loops too quickly, what is my best option for this? open to any suggestions, also is using a PlaceHolder to display my table the best option if not, what should I use? Thanks for any help in advance.

```
    protected void CreateTable()
    {
        int tblColumns = 20;
        int tblRows = 50;
        //Create the table
        Table tbl = new Table();

        tbl.CssClass = "table";
        //Add table
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(tbl);
        Random RandomNumber = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < tblRows; i++)
        {
            TableRow tr = new TableRow();
            for (int j = 0; j < tblColumns; j++)
            {
                TableCell tc = new TableCell();
                int Range = RandomNumber.Next(1, 99);
                tc.Text = Range.ToString();

                int tblCell = Convert.ToInt32(tc.Text);
                int thrsVal = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text);

                if (tblCell < thrsVal)
                {
                    tc.CssClass = "red";
                }
                else if (tblCell == thrsVal)
                {
                    tc.CssClass = "green";
                }
                else if (tblCell > thrsVal)
                {
                    tc.CssClass = "yellow";
                }
                else
                {

                }
                //Add Columns
                tr.Cells.Add(tc);
            }
            //Add Rows
            tbl.Rows.Add(tr);
        }
    }

    protected void btnGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CreateTable();
    }
```

Comment: what is PlaceHolder1?